# Constructor error using mXparser with Pythonnet

Tags: python, .net, interop, overloading, python.net

I am trying to use mXparser from Python. It loads without problem, but as soon as try to call the expression function with a string (as in the help examples), I get an error, `TypeError: no constructor matches given arguments`.

```
import clr  
dllpath = r'C:\...\GitHub\MathParser.org-mXparser\CURRENT\c-sharp\bin\Release\MathParser.org-mXparser.dll'
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser as mx
expr_01 = mx.Expression('2 + 1')
```

Initially I took this to mean that I needed to specify the type of the string I was passing, but I don't think this is it. Any ideas? I compiled the mXparser dll with .NET Framework 4.5.2 (I did not choose the option to make it COM-visible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run 
`mx.Expression.Overloads` to see what argument type it needs. The type can be imported by `from System import String`, etc

Explicitly, construct the c# type

```
from System import String
str3 = String('2 + 1')
expr_01 = mx.Expression(str3)
```